# What is this swiveling hook supplied with snowbard bindings for?

Tags: equipment, snowboarding

This is my second snowboard bindings, and there was this strange thing supplied with both. **What is it for?**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "snowboard leash."

A snowboard leash is used as a safety precaution to prevent occurrences of runaway snowboards that may injure others and/or destroy the snowboard<sub>[(1)](http://www.nyx.net/~mwallace/sb_faq/faq/816.htm)</sub>.

---

North Carolina, USA has required the use of such devices in their state according to [House Bill 334/ SL 2009-353](http://www.ncleg.net/Sessions/2009/Bills/House/PDF/H334v4.pdf).

**House Bill 334/ SL 2009-353 § 99C-2 (b) 5 states:**

> A skier shall have the following responsibilities: To wear retention straps, ski brakes, or other devices to prevent runaway skis or snowboards